# In iOS 11, how to make core data searchable in core spotlight

Tags: ios, core-data, ios11, corespotlight

As mentioned at WWDC, iOS 11 should have support to index `CoreData` so that it is searchable via `Spotlight`.  This is the WWDC presentation:

https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2017/210/

However, after watching the video and looking at docs, I still have no idea how to setup my core data objects so they are searchable from the phones spotlight search.

I guess the main questions are:

1.) How do you actually set which attributes of a certain object type are searchable.

2.) How do you setup a `NSCoreDataCoreSpotlightDelegate` and get it to process the data?  It looks like `NSPersistentStore` has a property

`var coreSpotlightExporter: NSCoreDataCoreSpotlightDelegate`

but it's readyonly :(

I couldn't find anything that explained this stuff clearly.  Thanks!

Comment: See my answer for how to use `NSCoreDataCoreSpotlightDelegate`.

Answer (score 8):

You do not set `coreSpotlightExporter` directly. Instead, set the `NSCoreDataCoreSpotlightExporter` option with your export delegate:

```
container.persistentStoreDescriptions.forEach {
    $0.setOption(MyCoreDataCoreSpotlightDelegate(forStoreWith:$0, model: container.managedObjectModel), forKey:NSCoreDataCoreSpotlightExporter)
}
```

I added this code before calling `loadPersistentStores(completionHandler:)`.

To set attributes and entities, you update the appropriate properties for `NSAttributeDescription` and `NSEntityDescription` or in your `.xcdatamodeld` in the UI.

Comment: The one would need to check the spotlight support in the UI for properties and display expression for entities.