# Memory hike with large database using NSCoreDataCoreSpotlightExporter

Tags: ios, core-data, core-data-migration, corespotlight

I have successfully implemented CoreSpolight Exporter on my Coredata setup as the following post:
[In iOS 11, how to make core data searchable in core spotlight](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45623020/in-ios-11-how-to-make-core-data-searchable-in-core-spotlight?rq=1)

Since my previous version of Coredata does not has Spotlight indexing, adding the delegate will now index the data. Which works great.

However, we've noticed that when the database is too big, we get a memory hike reaching 2GB during the initial app launch. Sometimes this causes the app to crash.

Is there anything can be done? I don't see how we can ask the delegate to batch inserts, or are we using this incorrectly?